# Is it possible to add Facebook "like" button without showing Control Style

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to add only Facebook Like button(without count,etc). Is it possible to add Facebook like button without showing `likeControlStyle (FBSDKLikeControlStyleStandard, FBSDKLikeControlStyleBoxCount)`?

Answer (score 2):

I tried solve this and for this I create a subclass the likeButton of Facebook SDK: `FBSDKLikeControlOnly`:

FBSDKLikeControlOnly.h

```
#import "FBSDKLikeControl.h"

@interface FBSDKLikeControlOnly : FBSDKLikeControl

@end
```

FBSDKLikeControlOnly.m

```
@implementation FBSDKLikeControlOnly

- (UIView *)_auxiliaryView {

    return nil;
}

@end
```

After, In your viewController you can use this new controller:

```
 FBSDKLikeControlOnly *likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControlOnly alloc] init];
 [likeButton setLikeControlStyle:FBSDKLikeControlStyleBoxCount];
 [likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers";
 likeButton.center = self.view.center;

 [self.view addSubview:likeButton];
```

I hope this help you.